# Error in multi-line sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can someone explain whats happening here?

[image]

Both are same query, with the only difference of multi-line and single line in SQL Developer.

The query-

```
SELECT (TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') -NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/(24*25*60*1000),'HOUR')) a FROM dual;
```

The above works, but the below won't-

```
SELECT (TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') -
              NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/(24*25*60*1000),'HOUR')) a FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like SQL Developer's parser requires the argument after its `-` operator to be on the same line. ...so this works:

```
SELECT (TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') 
- NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/(24*25*60*1000),'HOUR')) a 
FROM dual;
```

So the problem isn't multi-line per-se, but rather needing to have the operator (`-`) on the same line as its operand.  Why exactly?  I'd say either a bug, or just a sub-optimal implementation.

[Edit: as others have noted, the hyphen is the default [line continuation character](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=652359), which is why this works this way]

Comment: Wow! that almost felt like a magic. :P But this is weird. The answer you gave is true for only `-` operator, everything else like `+`, or multiplication `*`, division `/`, work fine

Comment: This is because the `-` character is used at the end of a line to explicitly continue it on the next line.  So when you ended the line with `-` it is used as the continuation, so you would need to start the following line with `-` for it to run correctly.

Comment: @user564636 I understand that in terms of SQL PLus's limitation to its `SQL>` prompt, but shoudn't an advanced IDE like SQL Developer overcome this anomaly?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.kuzbass.ru/docs/rdb702/oraclerdb/sqlrm7/sql_pro_008.html) website,

> "You can explicitly continue a line in interactive SQL by ending it
>   with a hyphen (-)."

You can see in your screenshot `EXECUTING`: `SELECT (TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY')    NUMTO`...

The minus symbol is missing.

Answer (score 1):

In sqlplus, a hyphen at the end of the line acts as a line continuation character.  See [Continuing a long line section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12170/ch5.htm#i1039736) here. Probably SQLDeveloper is doing the same thing. So don't put a hyphen at the end of a line.

Comment: I would think SQL Plus to have this feature but not an advanced IDE like SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run the last query without putting the minus on a new line by simply adding hyphen at the end of the first line. It seems like SQL Developer has the SQl*plus way of interpreting long commands
Try this

```
SELECT (TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') - -
       NUMTODSINTERVAL(1/(24*25*60*1000),'HOUR')) a FROM dual
```

Comment: Thats weird too! `--` is for comments isn't it, bit it works :)

Comment: @Annjawn `--` (no space in between) is used for comments.  Nicholas's example has a space in between them.

Comment: @user564636 it works even if you don't add the space in between.